# Сапфический

Tags: значение-слов

Интересует значение слова.
Нашёл лишь Сапфический стих, быть может есть другое толкование?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Наверное, возможны сапфические отношения, сапфическая любовь: сексуальная ориентация Сапфо - не секрет.

Comment: Точно. Нашёл в статье Вики подтверждение: "Слово «лесбиянка» происходит от названия её родного острова Лесбос, а в английском языке также используется образованное от её имени слово «сапфический»; оба этих слова стали применяться для обозначения женской гомосексуальности только в XIX веке. "

Answer (score 1):

Сапфический - соб. - свойственный греч. поэтессе Сапфо (7 - 6 в. до н. э.) или ее произведениям; различают 2 вида сапфического стиха (большой и малый) и два типа сапфической строфы (двустишную и более распространенную - четырехстишную).

(Словарь иностранных слов, 1933)